# "SELECT into statement" inside loop not working

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a **select into statement that works**, but when i put it inside a Loop, it fails.
Does anyone have any idea why this is happening??

Thank you!

Here's the code:

```
For o = 0 To x

            tables = ListBox1.Items.Item(o).ToString
            sqlstr = "SELECT * into dbo." & tables & " FROM OPENROWSET('MSDASQL', 'Driver=Microsoft Visual FoxPro Driver; SourceDB=C:\exports\DBF; SourceType = DBF ', 'SELECT * FROM " & tables & "')"
            mycmd = New SqlCommand
            sqlcon = New SqlConnection(con)
            mycmd.CommandText = sqlstr
            sqlcon.Open()
            mycmd.Connection = sqlcon
            mycmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            sqlcon.Close()
Next
```

When i try to execute this it gives me following error

```
    Cannot execute the query "SELECT * FROM AFED" against OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" 
for linked server "(null)". OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" 
for linked server "(null)" returned message 
"[Microsoft][ODBC Visual FoxPro Driver]File 'afed.dbf' does not exist.".
```

Comment: How should we know without the actual code?

Comment: please put more code for reference without the code everybody will downvote the question and eventually it will be closed

Comment: when i put a static value for "o", it runs without errors and adds the table to the database.

Comment: is there any error it throws ??

Comment: Cannot execute the query "SELECT * FROM AFED" against OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "(null)". 
OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "(null)" returned message "[Microsoft][ODBC Visual FoxPro Driver]File 'afed.dbf' does not exist.".

Answer (score 0):

Please check your foxpro db .. I think `afed` table does not exist in foxpro DB.and that is why you are not getting the error when put static value instead of `o`.

Comment: sir, it does exist. if i put any value in "o" as long as it is no more than the quantity of DBF's inside the SOURCEDB, it successfully adds the table to the database. however when i put the statement in a loop; that error shows up..